# How do I use output from python script in my Powershell application?

Tags: python, powershell

I have a power-shell GUI Application. Inside my application I call a python script. I want to display the output of the python script.

> test.py prints "hello world"

```
$dog.Add_Click({FixIndefinite}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($dog)


function FixIndefinite {
try { $outputBox.text = "Welcome"
      python .\test.py

    }
catch {$outputBox.text = "`nOperation could not be completed"}
```

Comment: Did you try using like this $cmdOutput = python .\test.py

Comment: This is assunming that your python environment varibale are all set ?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to powershell. $outputBox.text = python .\test.py worked thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$outputBox.text = python .\test.py
```

Comment: if you are satisfied with answer please mark the answer as correct.